# Rotating spinner arrow in android by 180

Tags: android-layout, android-spinner, android

Issue: 
I needed to implement Spinner for RTL languages such that text is aligned to right and down arrow towards left.I am able to acheive this alignment but the arrow is pointing upwards.
I do not want to use setRotation since it's available only from API level 11.
PFB the code I am using:

```
    //Creating spinner
    Spinner s=new RTLSpinner(this);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("list 1");
    list.add("list 2");
    list.add("list 3");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    //Fetching the background drawable of Spinner
    NinePatchDrawable drawable=(NinePatchDrawable)(((StateListDrawable)s.getBackground()).getCurrent());

    //Converting it into Bitmap
     Bitmap bmpOriginal = Bitmap  
             .createBitmap(  
                     drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),  
                     drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(),  
                     drawable.getOpacity() != PixelFormat.OPAQUE ? Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888  
                             : Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);  
     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpOriginal);  
     drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),  
             drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());  
     drawable.draw(canvas);

     //Rotating the image
     Bitmap bmResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpOriginal.getWidth(), bmpOriginal.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(bmResult); 
    tempCanvas.rotate(180, bmpOriginal.getWidth()/2, bmpOriginal.getHeight()/2);
    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, null);
    s.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bmResult));


   class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> textArray) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, textArray);
    }

    public TextView getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView viewObj = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView,
                parent);
        TextView optionView = (TextView) viewObj
                .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        optionView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        return viewObj;
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: So you want the arrow to point **up** (this would be the effect of a 180 degrees rotation)? I think it is better if you **move it on the left side** of the spinner, rather than rotating it 180°!

Comment: I want the arrow to point downwards.